# Can we execute a batch file (*.bat) using Application Domain?

Tags: c#, .net

Can we execute a batch file (*.bat) using Application Domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application Domains are a purely CLR concept, they have no relevancy to anything that's not a managed library, thus there's no way to run a batch file within an appdomain. The `Process` object that the batch file runs under will be tied to one specific appdomain, but it will still result in a separate process being instantiated to run your batch file.

There's some fairly good explanatory text under *Remarks* in the MSDN [AppDomain Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) documentation that should help you get a handle on what precisely an appdomain is, and what you can and can't do with one.

Answer (score 3):

No. AppDomain is a purely CLRs' concept, whereas `*.bat` files are executed "inside" usual Windows.

Comment: Apart from my question above, Application Domain cannot  execute unmanaged assemblies?

Frankly, I am new to Application Domain.

Comment: @xport Application Domain can execute unmanaged C++/CLI assemblies, but a batch file does not constitute an unmanaged assembly.

Comment: +1, but I would add batch files run in there own process as any other executable.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to execute a batch file from your C#, use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.bat";
myProcess.Start();
```

Batch files are not part of the CLR and therefor cannot be run within an AppDomain.

Comment: Your code snippet calls the batch file using process rather than ApplicationDomain. I intentionally choose ApplicationDomain because of its efficiency aspect.

Comment: My scenario does not allow multiple processes to run; it will break the scalability.

Comment: @xport - fair enough. You did not provide that detail in your question, and I assumed you may have not known about `Process`. In this case, I would have to agree with @Anton Gogolev - it is not possible to run a batch file within an AppDomain.